# Where insert main and css attributes for logo

Tags: css, html

I'm beginner in web programing and I'have small problem with understanding of HTML5 tags. The `main` tag is for main content but `filedset` can be in this tag or `main` tag should be in `filedset` tag ?
And web site logo how tags I should set for this ? I should insert `img` in other `div` or I should set all tags from this div to `img` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/adriansikora344/5t0Lzs0y/
or
https://jsfiddle.net/adriansikora344/ug3adstu/

Answer (score 0):

Main tag (quoted from w3c):

> The content inside the  element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms.

The fieldset tag is intended to group some form fields, so if you have a form in your web it's fine to get it wrapped by the main tag.

About the logo... This is a very open question. There is not a correct structure, I mean, depending on how you would like to organize contents or views you will need an HTML composition or another. I suggest you to try to create your page. Then, when you get stuck in some concrete problem, you can came back and create a new question with a detailed explanation of your problem and (this is important) an example of what are you tryin to accomplish your target.